# What's the opposite of chr() in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, ascii

In many languages there's a pair of functions, `chr()` and `ord()`, which convert between numbers and character values. In some languages, `ord()` is called `asc()`.

Ruby has `Integer#chr`, which works great:

```
>> 65.chr
A
```

Fair enough. But how do you go the other way?

```
"A".each_byte do |byte|
   puts byte
end
```

prints:

```
65
```

and that's pretty close to what I want. But I'd really rather avoid a loop -- I'm looking for something short enough to be readable when declaring a `const`.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

If String#ord didn't exist in 1.9, it does in 2.0:

```
"A".ord #=> 65
```

Answer (score 33):

In Ruby up to and including the 1.8 series, the following will both produce 65 (for ASCII):

```
puts ?A
'A'[0]
```

The behavior has changed in Ruby 1.9, both of the above will produce "A" instead.  The correct way to do this in Ruby 1.9 is:

```
'A'[0].ord
```

Unfortunately, the `ord` method doesn't exist in Ruby 1.8.

Comment: It's unfortunate that the "correct" way in Ruby 1.9 is so long, but at least it'll show up easier in searches for "ord".

Thanks for your very detailed answer.

Answer (score 13):

Try:

```
'A'.unpack('c')
```

Comment: Now that Ruby 1.9 has changed the meaning of 'A'[0], this is the more portable method.

Answer (score 10):

I'd like to +1 dylanfm and AShelly's comment but add the [0]:

`'A'.unpack('C')[0]`

The unpack call returns an Array containing a single integer, which is not always accepted where an integer is wanted:

```
$ ruby -e 'printf("0x%02X\n", "A".unpack("C"))'
-e:1:in `printf': can't convert Array into Integer (TypeError)
    from -e:1
$ ruby -e 'printf("0x%02X\n", "A".unpack("C")[0])'
0x41
$
```

I'm trying to write code that works on Ruby 1.8.1, 1.8.7 and 1.9.2.

Edited to pass C to unpack in uppercase, because unpack("c") gives me -1 where ord() gives me 255 (despite running on a platform where C's char is signed).

Answer (score 5):

Just came across this while putting together a pure Ruby version of Stringprep via RFCs.

Beware that `chr` fails outside [0,255], instead use 1.9.x - 2.1.x portable replacements:

```
[22] pry(main)> "\u0221".ord.chr
RangeError: 545 out of char range
from (pry):2:in 'chr'
[23] pry(main)> x = "\u0221".unpack('U')[0]
=> 545
[24] pry(main)> [x].pack('U')
=> "ȡ"
[25] pry(main)>
```

Comment: Thank you, this seems to be the only answer that gives `char` and its inverse in the case of unicode correctly

Comment: important context [here](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/17405) and [here](https://github.com/ruby/irb/issues/43) if anyone comes this way.

Answer (score 3):

Additionally, if you have the char in a string and you want to decode it without a loop:

```
puts 'Az'[0]
=> 65
puts 'Az'[1]
=> 122
```

Answer (score 2):

How about

> puts ?A

Answer (score 2):

You can have these:

```
65.chr.ord
'a'.ord.chr
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind pulling the values out of an array, you can use `"A".bytes`

Answer (score 0):

I'm writing code for 1.8.6 and 1.9.3 and I couldn't get any of these solutions to work in both environments :(

However, I came across another solution:
http://smajnr.net/2009/12/ruby-1-8-nomethoderror-undefined-method-ord-for-string.html

That didn't work for me either but I adapted it for my use:

```html
unless "".respond_to?(:ord)
  class Fixnum
    def ord
      return self
    end
  end
end
```

Having done that, then the following will work in both environments

```html
'A'[0].ord
```

Comment: When user18096 wrote their answer, `"A".unpack("C")[0]`, that was targeting Ruby 1.8.1, Ruby 1.8.7 and Ruby 1.9.2. Does it fail in your environment? What kind of failure?

Comment: Hi RJHunter, I am trying to convert a specific character in a string to its number value. The following code works in 1.9.3 but not 1.8.6.       
`self.status  = tagAccountString[4].unpack('C')[0]`       
In 1.8.6 I get     
`Exception undefined method `unpack' for 0:Fixnum processing main buffered tag data - exit`       
The following code works (with my proposed solution) in both environments        
`self.status  = tagAccountString[4].ord`        
Any advice (e.g. a better solution) is more than welcome

Comment: `tagAccountString[4]` returns a String in newer Rubies but used to return a Fixnum in Ruby 1.8. That's why you saw the error, `undefined method unpack for 0:Fixnum`. You could use `status = tagAccountString[4,1].unpack('C')[0]` or even `status, = tagAccountString.unpack('xxxxC')` if you always want to ignore four characters and convert the next one.

Comment: Thanks RJHunter for the explanation and alternative solutions. However, as "my" solution is more readable and reusable, I'll stick with that (unless there is a good reason not too?)