# How to identify character's language in Ruby/Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Given a character (one letter of a string), how could I identify to which language it belongs ? The options are: English, Russian, Hebrew.

Background: this character was entered by user in a form and then stored in a database.

It can be for example the first letter in one of these words:

- Hello
- Привет
- שלום

Comment: http://rubygems.org/gems/kenwaln-whatlanguage

Comment: What version of Ruby are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **UNICODE** standard is divided into "**blocks**". Go here:

http://www.unicode.org/charts/

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_block

http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode6.0.0/

and find unicode blocks (intervals) for each language.

My guess:

- [English](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_Controls_and_Basic_Latin)
- [Hebrew](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_and_HTML_for_the_Hebrew_alphabet)
- [Russian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyrillic_%28Unicode_block%29)

So for you its the matter of simple **number comparsion** for each character (unicode ordinal value). Very simple.

Comment: @Izap: Great! That's what I thought to do. Which Ruby function returns the unicode of the character ?

Comment: Glad you like it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/308749/whats-the-opposite-of-chr-in-ruby