# How to get the ascii code for "x"

Tags: ruby, ascii

I'm in the terminal and I'm running IRB. I'm trying to get the ASCII value of `x`. I know the value is `120`. That's correct right? When I type the following into my terminal this is the response I get:

```
puts ?x
(output) x
```

Why isn't it coming up 120?

Comment: Please see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/308904/1270789) - Ruby stopped supporting `?x` in v1.9.

Comment: Is your question whether you are correct about `120`?

Comment: Thanks Ken I appreciate it. Do you happen to know how I can find the value of x without using?x

Comment: My question is how do I ask what the value of x is if ?x isn't supported anymore. And is 120 the value of x?

Comment: Thanks Ken and Sawa. I got it figured out. I appreciate you taking time to help me.

Answer (score 1):

[`String#ord`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/String.html#method-i-ord) could be used to get the integer representation of a one-character string:

```
'x'.ord
# => 120
```

P.S: use `'x'` or `"x"` instead of `?x`.